# Duplicating grease pencil layers?

Tags: grease-pencil

when I try to duplicate grease pencil layers [using the "copy/paste" buttons](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching/Layers_and_Animation) I get a: "keyframe pasting not available for grease pencil mode"
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can duplicate Grease Pencil layers by clicking the Copy button in **Grease Pencil** panel located in <kbd>N</kbd> sidebar.

[image]

---

Note: This is a coming feature in **2.74**. More information see [here](https://developer.blender.org/rBd5f3aee). Currently you can try the [daily version](https://builder.blender.org/download/) if you have to.

Comment: I don't have that option in my version

Comment: @LeonCheung ... which  is your blender version??  I have 2.73a  and I don't have that option

Comment: Is it maybe an addon?

Comment: Same as yours. This is part of the huge improvements since 2.73. You need to create at least one layer there first.

Comment: don't have that button either in 2.73a (I wouldn't have started this thread if i had :) )

Comment: Oops, That's right. It seems a [new feature](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/Animation) that will show up in the coming 2.74. You may try the daily version [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> gives that message. You should use the duplicate function, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

if you want copy and paste all the layer, that is "imposible", the only way is to save the file with othen name and the import the gpencil with "append" or "link" `shift + F1`.. but only you will have 1 layer at the same time

Comment: thx, I don't want to duplicate the keyframes, but the whole layer, so that I have the same greasepencil animation twice. For that I create an empty layer and want to copy it to that....

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate the object the *Grease Pencil* layer is connected to. Rename the layer, and now add another layer and name it the same as the first object's layer. Now select the first object and then the one with two layers and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the objects. You now have one mesh with two identical layers. Now you can go into *Edit* mode and press <kbd>W</kbd> *> Remove Doubles*.

Comment: thx, I will try that. So far I use scenespace for the pencil, but that should be an easy fix

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.80:

1. Select the grease pencil object first.
2. Then, go to the object-data panel and then select the layer you want to duplicate.
3. On the right side there will be button bellow '+' and '-' button. Click on it.
4. Now, select the 'Duplicate Layer' to duplicate the layer.

See the image below for details.

[image: dupilcating a grease pencil layer]